# Is there any gem for getting mobike's geocode using ajax or html5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm looking for good gem for that.
To save geocodes, and fetch geocodes of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard package for geocoding:
https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Comment: Thanks! Do you always need to type in full address to get geocode?

Comment: You can do fuzzy text matching in geocode, and I usually truncate my text to limit length like 30.